# jquery data slide show like image slide show

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have bellow code which display 10 items and each item in each  of table

```
<div class="baner_main shadow">
<div id="adds">
<div class="latest_ads">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:800px">
<tbody>
<tr class="">
<?php
for($i=;$i<=10;$i++)
{
?>
<td class="even">
<img src="images/photo.gif" alt="" title=""><br>
<h3><a href="index.php?page=item&amp;id=11">Item Name</a></h3>
<p><strong>Price: 70.00 USD <br>  () <br> December 3, 2011</strong></p>
</td>
<?php
}
?>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

in 800 width of table it only show 5 items on screen one time.

what i need is

1. Move the first item and bring the next five items automatically after 10 sec using Jquery.
2. A small dot under table to move items next and previous with jquery.

this is common in image slide shows but i can't find any idea how to do with table.

if available give me any example link and i will it myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery cycle plugin http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/  and check http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/div.html for grouping set of items together. Most of the examples provided are Div based layouts. However, You can achieve the same effect using TD's as well. Let me know if you still need help

Comment: Thanks for help, its working but how can i get small image dots in place of numbers (1,2,3). as you see same small dots in most of image sliders. (thanks)

Comment: You can customize the pager by providing a call back function to build pager. Check the options reference. Let me know if you still need help